# Написание отрицательных местоимений через не- или ни-

Tags: орфография, местоимения, не-или-ни

Как правильно писать отрицательные местоимения: через "ни-" или через "не-"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Под ударением пишется приставка "не-".
Примеры: *н**е**кто, н**е**кий*.
Без ударения пишется "ни-".
Примеры: *никт**о**, никак**о**й, никог**о***.

Answer (score 0):

*Некто* и *некий* - это не отрицательные, а неопределённые местоимения!

Answer (score 0):

Но правило звучит верно: по ударением - е, без ударения - и.